# Writing values from dictionaries to CSV in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm reading the key: value pair from the list of dictionaries in a JSON file. The problem is I don't know how to write this in a CSV file. The code I have tried so far is:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq


arxml_json = open("C:\\Users\\abc\\xyz\\parser.json")
dataList = json.load(arxml_json)

# print(Results)
csv_file = "output.csv"
csv_columns = ['message_id', 'is_extended_frame','name', 'length', 'bit_length', 'factor', 'is_big_endian','is_signed,name', 'offset', 'start_bit', 'minimum', 'maximum', 'unit', 'recv_nodes', 'val_desc']

with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
    writer.writeheader()

for key in dataList['messages']:
    id = key['id']
    is_extended_frame = key['is_extended_frame']
    name = key['name']
    length = key['length']
    for value in key['signals']:
        bit_length = value['bit_length']
        factor = value['factor']
        is_big_endian = value['is_big_endian']
        #is_float = value['is_float']
        is_signed = value['is_signed']
        name = value['name']
        offset= value['offset']
        start_bit = value['start_bit']
        minimum = value['minimum']
        maximum = value['maximum']
        unit= value['unit']
        recv_nodes = value['recv_nodes']
        val_desc = value['val_desc']
```

The Json file looks like this:

```
"messages": [
        {
            "id": 666,
            "is_extended_frame": false,
            "name": "uptime",
            "length": 8,
            "signals": 
                [{
                "bit_length": 64,
                "factor": 1,
                "is_big_endian": true,
                "is_float": true,
                "is_signed": true,
                "name": "uptime",
                "offset": 98,
                "start_bit": 40,
                "minimum": 30,
                "maximum": 70,
                "unit": "m/s",
                "recv_nodes": "none",
                "val_desc": "-none-"
                },{
                "bit_length": 64,
                "factor": 1,
                "is_big_endian": true,
                "is_float": true,
                "is_signed": true,
                "name": "uptime",
                "offset": 98,
                "start_bit": 40,
                "minimum": 30,
                "maximum": 70,
                "unit": "m/s",
                "recv_nodes": "none",
                "val_desc": "-none-"
                }]

        },
```

I want to create a CSV file that will look like below:
[image: CSV]

Any leads on how can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will the `signals` array for a singular message always have only one element as shown in your example?

Comment: @awarrier99 No, the <signals> array can have more elements in it. I have updated my question. Please check.

Comment: Ok, so would you want a separate row for each of these where the `id`, `is_extended_frame`, `name`, and `length` properties stay the same, but the `signals` are different?

Comment: I updated my answer to accommodate multiple elements in `signals`

Comment: @awarrier99 Thank you! it worked perfectly. Can you explain what you were trying to do with temp and then del command?? I'm new to  Python so little explanation will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: No problem and sure. I just updated my post with a description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over all of the `dict`s in the messages list inside of the `dict` returned by your `json.load` call and collapse the `signals` list so that each key in the sub-`dict` becomes a key in the overall `dict` so you don't have to explicitly pull out each property:

```
with open('test.json') as arxml_json:
    dataList = json.load(arxml_json)

# print(Results)
csv_file = "output.csv"
csv_columns = ['message_id', 'is_extended_frame', 'message_name', 'length', 'bit_length', 'factor', 'is_big_endian','is_signed', 'signal_name', 'offset', 'start_bit', 'minimum', 'maximum', 'unit', 'recv_nodes', 'val_desc']

with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
    writer.writeheader()

    for message in dataList['messages']:
        for signals in message['signals']:
            temp = {k: v for k, v in message.items() if k != 'signals'}
            temp['message_name'] = temp['name']
            temp['message_id'] = temp['id']
            del temp['name']
            del temp['id']
            for key, value in signals.items():
                    if key == 'name':
                        temp['signal_name'] = value
                    else:
                        temp[key] = value
            del temp['is_float'] # don't care about this field
            print(temp)
            writer.writerow(temp)
```

What this is doing is first, iterating through all of the messages in your JSON, and then iterating through all of the possible `dict`s in `message['signals']`. During each iteration over `signals`, `temp` is initially created as a copy of the `message` dictionary, excluding the `signals` `list`, because we want to copy those items out of the `list`. Then, it renames some of the properties according to the requirements in your screenshot: `name` in the top-level becomes `message_name` and `id` becomes `message_id`. it uses the `del` keyword to remove the key-value pair from the `dict` once it has renamed it. Then, for all of the key-value pairs in the current `signal` `dict`, it assigns them to `temp`. Finally, it deletes the field which you don't show in your screenshot and then writes the `temp` `dict` to the file

Answer (score 1):

the nature of comma separated value (csv) file is a long string that separate certain value with comma.

1. create a string that separated with value

```py
data_to_write = []
data_to_write.append("id_no")
data_to_write.append("is_extended_frame_bool")
# and so on

# join all the content in the data_to_write_list to one long string
string_to_append = ",".join(map(str,data_to_write))
```

2. append the string to csv file

```py
output_file_name = "mydata.csv"
with open(output_file_name,"a") as file_object:
    file_object.write(string_to_append +"\n")

# if "\n" not be use, it will become a long line
```